# Rails+Devise+OmniAuth: Twitter authentication and skipping email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model, omniauth

I've found a few similar topics here on SO, but none of them was working for me.
I have this in the **User** model:

```
def email_required?
  super && provider.blank?
end

  def self.find_for_twitter_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
    data = access_token.extra.raw_info

    if user = User.where(:provider => 'twitter', :uid => data.id).first
      user
    else # Create a user with a stub password. 
      user = User.new(:first_name => data.first_name,
                          :last_name => data.last_name,
                          :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
                          :provider => 'twitter',
                          :uid => data.id,
                          :terms_of_use => true)
      user.save(:validation => false)
    end
    return user if user
  end
```

But all the time when I try to authenticate through Twitter, I get

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: users.email may not be NULL: INSERT INTO "users"...
```

I've spent a few hours of solving this issue and I am really despair... I would be grateful for every help.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way: add a fake email and skip confirmation.

```
user = User.new(:first_name => data.first_name,
                :last_name => data.last_name,
                :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
                :provider => 'twitter',
                :email => auth.uid.to_s+'@twitter.com',
                :uid => data.id,
                :terms_of_use => true)
user.skip_confirmation! # only if you add devise :confirmable
user.save
```

Comment: I would like to use a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Validation added to your schema. You can change column properties by doing migration, but, in my opinion, it more bad idea.